# Maximizing final return - Fixed Income (Dedication.gms)

Tags: optimization, finance

I am trying to maximize the final return instead of minimizing the initial costs in the GAMS dedication model, which can be found at [GAMS Dedication Model](https://www.gams.com/latest/finlib_ml/libhtml/finlib_Dedication.html). I tried adding a variable $v_T$ but I am getting an error that states that it is not used in the equation CashFlowCon(t). How can I go about editing the equation such that $v_T$ can be incorporated into it? Some help will be deeply appreciated, as I am still new to GAMS.

If it helps, my code which is built upon the original GAMS code found in the link above, is as follows:

```
$TITLE Dedication models
$eolcom //

* Dedication.gms:  Dedication models.

SET Time 'Time periods' /2001 * 2011/;

ALIAS (Time, t, t1, t2);

SCALARS
   Now      'Current year'
   Horizon  'End of the Horizon';

Now = 2001;
Horizon = CARD(t)-1;

PARAMETER
   tau(t) 'Time in years';

* Note: time starts from 0

tau(t)  = ORD(t)-1;

SET Bonds 'Bonds universe'
    /DS-8-06, DS-8-03, DS-7-07,
     DS-7-04, DS-6-11, DS-6-09,
     DS-6-02, DS-5-05, DS-5-03, DS-4-02
/;


ALIAS(Bonds, i);

SCALAR
         spread         'Borrowing spread over the reinvestment rate';

PARAMETERS
         Price(i)       'Bond prices'
         Coupon(i)      'Coupons'
         Maturity(i)    'Maturities'
         Liability(t)   'Stream of liabilities'
         rf(t)          'Reinvestment rates'
         F(t, i)        'Cashflows'
;

* Bond data. Prices, coupons and maturities from the Danish market

$INCLUDE "BondData.inc"

* Copy/transform data. Note division by 100 to get unit data, and
* subtraction of "Now" from Maturity date (so consistent with tau):

Price(i)    = BondData(i,"Price")/100;
Coupon(i)   = BondData(i,"Coupon")/100;
Maturity(i) = BondData(i,"Maturity") - Now;

* Calculate the ex-coupon cashflow of Bond i in year t:

F(t,i) = 1$(tau(t) = Maturity(i))
            +  coupon(i) $ (tau(t) <= Maturity(i) AND tau(t) > 0);
display F;

//Data for reinvestment and borrowing
rf(t)  = 0.04;
spread = 0.02;

PARAMETER
         Liability(t) Liabilities
         /2002 =  80000, 2003 = 100000, 2004 = 110000, 2005 = 120000,
          2006 = 140000, 2007 = 120000, 2008 =  90000, 2009 =  50000,
          2010 =  75000, 2011 = 150000/;

POSITIVE VARIABLES
        x(i)           'Face value purchased'
        surplus(t)     'Amount of money reinvested'
        borrow(t)      Amount of money borrowed;


VARIABLE
        v0             'Upfront investment'
        vT             'Horizon Returns';

EQUATION

       CashFlowCon(t) Equations defining the cashflow balance;

CashFlowCon(t)..  SUM(i, F(t,i) * x(i) ) +
                 ( v0 - SUM(i, Price(i) * x(i)) )         $(tau(t) = 0) +
                  borrow(t)                               $(tau(t) < Horizon) +
                 ( ( 1 + rf(t-1) ) * surplus(t-1) )       $(tau(t) > 0) =E=
                 surplus(t) + Liability(t)                $(tau(t) > 0) +
                 ( 1 + rf(t-1) + spread ) * borrow(t-1)   $(tau(t) > 0);


MODEL Dedication 'PFO Chapter 4' /all/;

SOLVE Dedication MAXIMIZING vT USING LP;

PARAMETER
      PortYield(t) Portfolio yield at liability dates;

PortYield(t)$(tau(t) > 0) =   - LOG(CashFlowCon.M(t)) / tau(t) ;

DISPLAY v0.l, surplus.l, x.l;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer, and I got the solution through other means, for records, I'll just put it here for future reference. The code is as follows:

```
$TITLE Dedication models

* Dedication.gms:  Dedication models.

SET Time Time periods /2001 * 2011/;

ALIAS (Time, t, t1, t2);

SCALARS
   Now      'Current year'
   Horizon  'End of the Horizon';

Now = 2001;
Horizon = CARD(t)-1;

PARAMETER
   tau(t) 'Time in years';

* Note: time starts from 0

tau(t)  = ORD(t)-1;


SET Bonds 'Bonds universe'
    /DS-8-06, DS-8-03, DS-7-07,
     DS-7-04, DS-6-11, DS-6-09,
     DS-6-02, DS-5-05, DS-5-03, DS-4-02/;


ALIAS(Bonds, i);

SCALAR
         spread         'Borrowing spread over the reinvestment rate';

PARAMETERS
         Price(i)       'Bond prices'
         Coupon(i)      'Coupons'
         Maturity(i)    'Maturities'
         Liability(t)   'Stream of liabilities'
         rf(t)          'Reinvestment rates'
         F(t, i)        'Cashflows';

* Bond data. Prices, coupons and maturities from the Danish market

$INCLUDE "BondData.inc"

* Copy/transform data. Note division by 100 to get unit data, and
* subtraction of "Now" from Maturity date (so consistent with tau):

Price(i)    = BondData(i,"Price")/100;
Coupon(i)   = BondData(i,"Coupon")/100;
Maturity(i) = BondData(i,"Maturity") - Now;

* Calculate the ex-coupon cashflow of Bond i in year t:

F(t,i) = 1$(tau(t) = Maturity(i))
            +  coupon(i) $ (tau(t) <= Maturity(i) AND tau(t) > 0);

* For simplicity, we set the short term rate to be 0.03 in each period

rf(t) = 0.04;
spread = 0.02;

DISPLAY F;

PARAMETER
         Liability(t) 'Liabilities'
         /2002 =  80000, 2003 = 100000, 2004 = 110000, 2005 = 120000,
          2006 = 140000, 2007 = 120000, 2008 =  90000, 2009 =  50000,
          2010 =  75000, 2011 = 150000/;

POSITIVE VARIABLES
        x(i)           'Face value purchased'
        surplus(t)     'Amount of money reinvested'
        borrow(t)      'Amount of money borrowed'
;


VARIABLE
        v0             'Upfront investment'
        VplusFinal     'Final value of vplus to be maximized in model 2'
;

SCALAR b0              'fixed budget';

EQUATION
Initial(t)             'Initialization of the investment'
Initial2(t)            'Initialization of the investment in model 2'
CashFlowCon(t)         'Equations defining the cashflow balance'
Final(t)               'Horison constraint'
FinalSurplus           'Final surplus to be maximized in model 2'
;

Initial(t)$(tau(t)=0)..      v0 =E= SUM(i, Price(i) * x(i)) + surplus(t) - borrow(t);

Initial2(t)$(tau(t)=0)..      b0 =E= SUM(i, Price(i) * x(i)) + surplus(t) - borrow(t);


CashFlowCon(t)$(tau(t)>0)..  SUM(i, F(t,i) * x(i) ) + borrow(t) + ( ( 1 + rf(t-1) ) * surplus(t-1) ) =E=
                             surplus(t) + Liability(t)  + ( 1 + rf(t-1) + spread ) * borrow(t-1);

Final(t)$(tau(t)=Horizon)..  borrow(t) =E= 0;

FinalSurplus..               VplusFinal =E= sum(t$(ord(t)=card(t)), surplus(t) );


MODEL Dedication 'PFO Model 4.2.3' /Initial, CashFlowCon, Final/;

MODEL Dedication2 /Initial2, CashFlowCon, Final, FinalSurplus/

SOLVE Dedication MINIMIZING v0 USING LP;
DISPLAY v0.l, borrow.l, surplus.l, x.l;


b0 = v0.l;

SOLVE Dedication2 MAXIMIZING VplusFinal USING LP;
DISPLAY VplusFinal.l, borrow.l, surplus.l, x.l;
```